# I created an ERC20 Token long time ago, and someone sent Ether to the contract.

Tags: contract-invocation

I created an ERC20 Token long time ago, and someone sent Ether to the contract. instead of invoking some token transfer function. Any way to get the ether out (i don't have the ABI, but it was just some standard token contract)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The default [standard token contract](https://github.com/ConsenSys/Tokens/blob/master/Token_Contracts/contracts/StandardToken.sol) does not accept Ether as non of the functions are marked as `payable`. This modifier was introduced quite a while ago and I assume your contract did not yet require it - hence all functions (including the fallback function) just accept Ether. The bad news: There is no way to get Ether out of such a contract - it is a perfect financial black hole that only sucks up Ether without even a theoretical way of getting them out again. Several people loosing Ether in that way was the reason why the `payable` modifier was introduced so that by default a contract does not just accept Ether that get thrown at it.